# Probability Inequality Exercise

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation, probability-limit-theorems

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be non-negative. Show that if $E[|X|^{n}]$ is finite, then:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}P(|X|\geq x) = 0$

**Attempt at Solution**

By Markov's inequality, we have:

$x^{n}P(|X|\geq x) \leq E[|X|^{n}]$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Is it true that: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}E[|X|^{n}] = 0$? If so, I can't understand why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[|X|^n]$ does not depend on $x$. If it helps you, write Markov's inequality using $\epsilon$ instead of $x$ to avoid confusion:

$$P(|X|\geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{E[|X|^p]}{\epsilon^p}.$$

This is true for all $\epsilon>0$, and the numerator is independent of $\epsilon$.

To prove your result, though, you need more than just Markov. Here's a sketch:

$$E[|X|^n]=\int_0^\infty P(|X|^n>x)dx=\int_0^\infty nu^{n-1}P(|X|>u)du,$$

where $u=x^{1/n}$. Now you need $u^{n-1}P(|X|>u)=o(1/u)$, which will imply your limit (i.e. compare to $f(u)=1/u$ which is not integrable). There are some details here that need to be filled in.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm still not sure how this proves that $\epsilon^{p}P(|X| \geq \epsilon)$ goes to zero. Does $P(|X| \geq \epsilon)$ dominate $\epsilon^{p}$?

Comment: @Rdrr: see edit.

Comment: Pardon me again, but is the following justifiable: $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon^{p}P(|X|\geq x) \leq \lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty}E[|X|^{p}] \leq \lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty}\frac{E[|X|^{p}]}{\epsilon^{p}}$

Comment: $E[|X|^p]$ is a constant. What you're saying is equivalent to the deduction $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \infty} 5 \leq \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow\infty} \frac{5}{\epsilon^p}=0$.